# Enlarge a partition without losing data with Windows 7 diskmgmt?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, disk-management

I have a 320GB hard drive currently partitioned as below:

[image]

A long time ago, a computer expert formatted my hard drive like this because I wanted to install Ubuntu. I'm now ready to do this, but I'll never need so much free space (103.09GB). I want to enlarge the D:\ volume because it already has lots of data on it.

I know that when I open `diskmgmt.msc`, I could possibly enlarge the D:\ volume using some free space from the unformatted 103.09GB volume, because the program offers me the option to enlarge. However I'm afraid that I might lose data doing this.

Is it possible to enlarge the partition with this Windows 7 tool or am I better using GParted via "Try Ubuntu" on my Live CD? Would either of them cause data loss in this scenario?

Comment: I have seen way too many people here use the Windows Disk Manager, and have problems requiring much more troubleshooting. I would not since there are better tools that run flawlessly. I would go with @Mehrdad on this one. I have also never seen a tool like this fail in 17 years, but it is good that you realize the importance of backups (based on your comment below). +1 for that.

Comment: okay, I'll have a look at partition master. Thanks. This tool never failed in 17 years?

Comment: What I meant was this tool or tools exactly like it. But no, I have never had a similar tool fail in 17 years, but I have seen people here have nightmarish problems with the Windows Disk Manager.

Answer (score 5):

Both GParted and Windows 7 *diskmgmt* are able to shrink and extend NTFS partitions without data loss. The risk is always there, but very small – in particular, extending is a very simple operation, compared to shrinking or moving.

I've used GParted for this myself several times and it worked perfectly. As for *diskmgmt* – it's part of Windows, so it surely should know how to deal with its own filesystem.

Comment: +1 for "As for diskmgmt – it's part of Windows, so it surely should know how to deal with its own filesystem".

Comment: @TFM, It's part of Windows, so it surely has bugs....

Answer (score 1):

Repartitioning *always* introduces a risk of data loss or corruption during operations, but from my experience it's pretty rare.  To be sure, make a backup first; and then use either method (personally I'd use GPartEd).

Comment: thanks! Yes, backups are always a necessary step before trying out something :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not your system partition, you can use whatever tool you want. Both **GParted** and **diskmgmt.msc** are reliable tools.

The important thing is that your drive is not converted to "**Dynamic**", not all partitioning tools can (could?) handle them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager#Basic_volumes_and_dynamic_volumes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: okay, because I never bothered about this subject. But it seems like most of the disks are basic disks by default...? How to see if my disks are basic or dynamic?

Comment: On the left side, under "Datenträger 0" it says "basic" (basis).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Easus Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/), it's awesome.

The disk manager has some **bugs** where, if you click in the wrong order, it can delete the wrong partition. (Edit: I couldn't reproduce this on a new virtual machine, but it happened to me on my real machine. I'm not going to try to reproduce it there!) Be careful what you do there.

---

#### Note:

It's worth mentioning that *extending* a partition with Disk Manager has never been problematic for me (or anyone I know). Don't worry about data loss. Just be careful to avoid *deleting* anything with Disk Management.

Comment: Any sources on these "bugs"? There may be several bugs in various Windows tools, but if the diskmgmt bug is even worse now, why not throw a link or two about how "severe" it is? After all, it would become a  major subject for discussion by now.

Comment: @TFM: In XP, when you right-click a partition on the visual panel and click Delete Partition, it *selects a different partition accidentally* before asking you, and *then* asks for confirmation; if you continue without noticing this, you delete the wrong partition. (If you don't believe me, try it. Install XP on a virtual machine, try this, and see what happens.) In Windows 7, I remember encountering a similar bug, though it was a while back -- IIRC, it doesn't *show* you that the selection has changed, but it has. If I reproduce it I'll list the steps.

Comment: @TFM: Another bug I've noticed is that if you're unlucky and have some *logical* partitions and try to delete one of them with Disk Management, the last partition will suddenly extend to *beyond* the end of the disk. (E.g. I get a 700-GiB partition at the end of a 500-GiB disk.) It's happened to me a couple of times now, and it needed some pretty serious recovery. If you'd like, I can try to reproduce that too, and give you the steps.

Comment: +1 This is the tool I would use also.

Comment: @TFM: Classic example of the bug I was referring to [just posted on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/415964/how-do-get-my-windows-7-partition-back-after-a-blue-screen).

Comment: @Mehrdad - There is no evidence the user didn't select the wrong partition. Infact there is no evidence you didn't either.  There is no evidence this bug even exists, you never told us how to reproduced the results, and even point out, you couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not stupid, I know what I did. It's happened to me **multiple** times -- I just don't *know* how to reproduce it (on Windows 7) -- but I can reproduce it on XP (just right-click a partition at the bottom after opening the window and press Delete, and notice the selection sometimes changes). But heck, if you don't believe me then I really don't care enough to try to convince you otherwise...