# On Windows (and PC), which Partition Recovery tool is a good, reliable one?

Tags: partitioning, boot, multi-boot, partition-recovery

This is related to question: [How do get my Windows 7 partition back after a blue screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/415964/how-do-get-my-windows-7-partition-back-after-a-blue-screen)  about losing the Windows 7 partition completely.

I wonder if a Partition Recovery tool is a good, reliable one?  There seem to be 4 that are free listed as top of Google search of "Partition Recovery":   Active@ Partition Recovery ( http://partition-recovery.com ), Mini Tool Partition Recovery, DiskInternals Partition Recovery, and EaseUS Partition Recovery.

Is one of them a good and reliable one?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Mini Tool Recovery.

With MT Recovery I restored very easy 2 logical partitions.

Partition Wizzard (same company) seems also quite reliable for partition operations.

Comment: I used Mini Tool Recovery on Vista to recover my Win 7 partition, it said "Please select the partition you need from the following list"... and I chose the partition to recover.  (I chose Win 7).  And Mini Tool actually went ahead and deleted my Vista partition after saying it is in use and "restart".  I guess it meant "Choose the partition you need" and it will delete the ones you didn't choose.  Not "Choose the partition you need to recover".

Answer (score 0):

The EaseUS one will attempt to recover files, but will not make any attempt on a partition.  In a recent test of it, it found essentially nothing on a Mac HFSJ+ disk.  I have confirmed this with their tech support department.

DataRescue  from Prosoft is another one.  It also does not attempt to rebuild a partition, but only scans the disk space for files. (Based on version 4.)  I have a tech support query in about this.