# windows 7 created an OEM partition on a 160Gb partition

Tags: oem, partition-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Windows (and PC), which Partition Recovery tool is a good, reliable one?](https://superuser.com/questions/415995/on-windows-and-pc-which-partition-recovery-tool-is-a-good-reliable-one)

I installed windows 7 and it created an OEM partition on a 160Gb partition which formally contained date so how can i recover the data from the partition

Comment: Its unlikely you will be able to recover all your data, this is what data backups are for, I hope you have them.

Comment: This is not the same as [*On Windows (and PC), which Partition Recovery tool is a good, reliable one?*](http://superuser.com/questions/415995/on-windows-and-pc-which-partition-recovery-tool-is-a-good-reliable-one). That question is a general partition question, but this one is specifically about the **OEM recovery partition**.